# I am trying to read user input "single" "married" "legally separated" "widow/er" only

Tags: java

```
 /*
```

I am trying to read user input "single" "married" "legally separated" "widow/er" only.
*/

```
public static String readStatus() {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 String status = "";
 do {
 System.out.print("Enter the status of the taxpayer: ");
 status = scan.nextLine();
 if (status != 'single' && status != 'married' && status != 'legally separated' && status !='widow/er'); 
 
 System.out.println("You have to type single. married, legally separated or widow/er");
 } while (status == 'single' && status == 'married' && status == 'legally separated' && status =='widow/er');
```

return readStatus;}

Comment: Would you please indent your code properly so we can read it without too much strain? Your IDE can do it for you — and for us. Thank you.

Comment: [I downvoted because if we cannot read your code, we cannot help you.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/).

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned a `String return type` in your `readStatus()` function,but you didn't put return statement.I think this would work fine.

```
        public static String readStatus() {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String status = "";
         do {
         System.out.print("Enter the status of the taxpayer: ");
         status = scan.nextLine();
         if (status != 'single' | status != 'married' | status != 'legally separated' | status !='widow/er'){
         System.out.println("You have to type single. married, legally separated or widow/er");
return;
    }
return status;
         } while (status == 'single' | status == 'married' | status == 'legally separated' | status =='widow/er');
```

Comment: but the problem is it keeps showing "invalid character constant"

Comment: Hello,Can you please show us the error message also.